# Fade out character by character in text using jQuery

Tags: jquery

In the code below I have a line of text "A B C" that I would like to fade out character by character, i.e. `C` is faded out first, then `B` and finally `A`. The code works, but I think that my solution is very clumpsy. If the text has more letters, then the code must be extended for each letter with callback after callback...

Can this be solved in a more neat way? Can the fadeOuts be placed in sequence instead of nested callbacks?

My final goal is to fade out a text character by character and then fade in a new text, character by character... Just like a Powerpoint animation :)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    $("#C").fadeOut(300, function() {
      $("#B").fadeOut(300, function() {
        $("#A").fadeOut(300);
      });
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <button>Click to fade out character by character</button><br><br>

  <div>
    <span id="A">A</span>
    <span id="B">B</span>
    <span id="C">C</span>
  </div>
```

Comment: are you going to have A B C inside div separately as in the above code or just on line ABC

Comment: No, not necessary... It's more likely that I would like to have a line of text like: `<div>Unfaded text <spans of text that fades> A B C</spans> </div>`

Answer (score 3):

You can first select `span`'s in reversed order and then use `each` loop and inside use `delay` with (`time` * `index`) on `fadeOut()`

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  $($("span").get().reverse()).each(function(i) {
    $(this).delay(400 * i).fadeOut(300)
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Click to fade out character by character</button><br><br>

<div>
  <span id="A">A</span>
  <span id="B">B</span>
  <span id="C">C</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/d0326z9m/

```
$("button").click(function() {
    var child = $('div').children();

    var i = child.length;
    setInterval(function() {
        $('#' + $(child[i-1]).attr('id')).fadeOut();
        i--;
        if( i < 0 ){
            window.clearInterval();
        }
    }, 300);
 });
```

In this solution, doesn't matter how may children you have inside a div it will perform perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I have mad solution where you don't have to write each character in span inside dom , instead you can just type in the string and fade out each character in reverse order

```
<div class="text">Phone is great</div>
```

Javscript code:

```
var queue = [];
var input = $(".text").text();
for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {

  queue.push("<span class='charToFade'>" + input.charAt(i) + "</span>");

}
$(".text").text("");
while(queue.length>0)
 {
  $(".text").append(queue.shift());
}

$($("span").get().reverse()).each(function(i) {
    $(this).delay(400 * i).fadeOut(300)
 })
```

See the [jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/obrt9ag7/12/)